# windows 8.1 hosts file # redirect this is just a bad ideas

Tags: windows, localhost, hosts

I've been editing my host file for a while never had this kind of problem. A few days ago I'm not sure either windows or a malware override my host file

For example if I did this

`127.0.0.1 yk-sms.localhost
::1 yk-sms.localhost`

when I restart my windows it change to this.

`#redirect this is just a bad ideas 127.0.0.1 yk-sms.localhost
#redirect this is just a bad ideas ::1 yk-sms.localhost`

It only happen to .localhost if I'm im using something like de.abc.com it will stay as it is.
Edited:
I've restart in safe mode and everything is ok. Try to add into windows defender exeption but windows defender disabled and i can;t turn it on. Already check in action center and no windows defender or any other application running to replace the windows defender. I'm using Avast antivirus.

Comment: Have you tried rebooting in Safe Mode? Seems like a virus to me.

Comment: in safe mode everything is ok.

Comment: I'm having exact same issue since I updated Windows (8.1) and 'Connectify' (on 16 Nov, 2014).

Comment: Connectify is doing this for me.